The heatmap is not shown for all years in echarts4r calendar
I am using echarts4r calendar displaying four years. The heatmap colors are only working for the first and last year.
Here is the code:
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "day")
values <- rnorm(length(dates), 20, 6)
year <- data.frame(date = dates, values = values)

# calendar multiple years
year |>
  dplyr::mutate(year = format(date, "%Y")) |>
  group_by(year) |>
  e_charts(date) |>
  e_calendar(range = "2020", top = 40) |>
  e_calendar(range = "2019", top = 260) |>
  e_calendar(range = "2018", top = 460) |>
  e_calendar(range = "2017", top = 660) |>
  e_heatmap(y=values, coord_system = "calendar",name=values,calendar=0) |>
  e_heatmap(y=values, coord_system = "calendar",name=values,calendar=1) |>
  e_heatmap(y=values, coord_system = "calendar",name=values,calendar=2) |>
  e_heatmap(y=values, coord_system = "calendar",name=values,calendar=3) |>
  e_visual_map(max = 30)

I have added "e_heatmap(y=values, coord_system = "calendar",name=values,calendar=1) |>" for each calendar Index but it is still not working.

Are you sure that this not only the case in the RStudio viewer? If I display it in a browser in full-screen, I see all years.
